# FQL Queries/API Calls make my page impossible slow (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, facebook, performance, facebook-fql

Total page load times have been ranging from 4-8 seconds, and for some reason the page doesn't even begin to load until it's made the API call. So even though the major API calls are at the bottom of the page (and script), nothing else on the page will load beforehand.

What's the best way to go about this? The most problematic API call is

```
$result = $facebook->api('/fql?q=select+uid,+name,+is_app_user+from+user+where+uid+in+(select+uid2+from+friend+where+uid1=me())+and+is_app_user=1');
```

Which finds the list of the user's friends using my app. In addition, I am making multiple api calls to get the names of users who are not that person's friend.

If it is impossible to speed up the API call, how can I at least get the rest of my page to load while FQL runs?

Comment: "So even though the major API calls are at the bottom of the page" It's PHP, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook api is very slow, you may want to make fb api calls through the javascript api and only through php if it is absolutely neccessary. Ajax is your best friend here. Making client side calls only also has the benefit that maybe critical user data never touches the server and that's a good argument for your site. People are very cautious these days.

Comment: And do not forget to cache stuff when using fb api calls! Like names of people, which do not change very often.